# Laravel MySQL Error 1054

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, delete-row, mysql-error-1054

I have this little annoying problem trying to delete a row in a paginated grid in Laravel, which worked fine a few days ago, and NOW, i'm getting this problem in all my grids whenever I try to delete any record. Here's an example of the error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.id' 
 in 'where clause' (SQL: delete from `users` where `id` = 9)
```

Now my actual code:

Migration up()

```
Schema::create('users', function(Blueprint $table){
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('username', 50);
    $table->string('password', 50);
    $table->string('email', 50);
    $table->tinyInteger('roles_id');
    $table->string('remember_token', 255);
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

View

```
{{ Form::open(array('action' => array('UserController@delete_user'), 'method' => 'delete')) }}
{{ Form::submit('Delete', array('class'=>'btn btn-danger', 'title'=>'Delete', 'style'=>'width:70px;height:35px;margin-left:100px;')) }}
{{ Form::hidden('id','',array('id'=>'identifier')) }}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

Route

```
Route::delete('users/delete', array('uses'=>'UserController@delete_user'))->before('auth');
```

Controller UserController

```
public function delete_destroy(){
    $id = Input::get('id');
    User::findOrFail($id)->delete();
    return Redirect::route('users');
}
```

Model User

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    protected $table = 'users';

    protected $hidden = array('password');

    protected $fillable = array('username', 'email', 'password', 'roles_id');
    public static $accessible = array('username', 'email', 'roles_id');

    private static function rules(){
        return array(
                    'username' => 'required|min:6|max:20|unique:users,username,"'.Input::get('id').'"',
                    'password' => 'required|min:8',
                    'email'    => 'required|email',
                    'roles_id' => 'required|numeric|min:1',
                    );
    }
//Bunch of other native functions
}
```

That's pretty much how all my routes, views, models and controllers look.

I'm only having trouble with deleting records though, creating and updating works fine.
Delete was working fine up until a few days ago, when I last deleted a record.
Today I was trying something different in a view, going from create to update, then when I tried to delete it, the previously quoted error message came up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the cause of the errors. Turns out I had triggers for 4 tables, which went something like this. The following example is just for the users table though:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `delete_privileges` AFTER DELETE ON `users` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM users_controllers_actions 
       WHERE users_controllers_actions.users_id=users.id;
END;
```

Guess that wasn't the right syntax... Maybe DELETED.id or OLD.id... I'm not used to using triggers in MySQL, but in SQL Server.

I'm not doing what I was supposed to do by using Foreign Key Constraints... which I didn't set at first because it gave me syntax errors. However, if anyone could tell me what the right syntax would be for creating triggers like the one I was obviously trying to create, I'd appreciate it.